# Xcode: Labels placed in Storyboard won't appear in the App Simulation

Tags: ios, swift

I am using Xcode 6 (Beta 6) (Sorry, I had to, Xcode 5 doesn't run on my Mac) and as a programming language I'm using Swift instead of Objective-C, wich is the main reason I couldn't find any help yet. My problem is pretty much exactly what's in the title:

I have 1 Label, 1 Text Input and 1 Button on my Storyboard, and all of them will appear in the app simulation. But when I trie to add another Label ("Please use a capital first letter") it won't appear in the simulation.

**Storyboard:** [Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlyTg.png)

**iOS Simulation:** [iOS Simulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3RI5.png)

**Code:**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameSubTitle: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    @IBAction func nameInputAction(nameTextField: UITextField) {
        nameLabel.text = "Hi, \(nameTextField.text)!"
        if nameTextField.text == "sarah" {
            nameLabel.text = "Hi, Sara!"
        }
        else if nameTextField.text == "Sarah" {
            nameLabel.text = "Hi, Sara!"
        }
    }
    @IBAction func nextButton(buttonNext: UIButton) {
        nameLabel.text = "What about a status?"
    }
}
```

Thanks for answering and sorry, reputation not high enough to post images...

Comment: Not sure about the label but why would you trust the user to capitalize the first letter when you can do that yourself? Use `myString.capitalizedString` to capitalize the first letter of every word in your string

Comment: Double check you have set the auto layout constraints appropriately in IB that there are no warnings about them when building...

Comment: Thanks for the myString.capitalizedString stuff :D

Answer (score 0):

My problem was with the autolayout constraints.  Without properly setting them on my widgets, the label widgets were behind the corresponding textField widget.  I took the suggestion of @Mike Pollard, in the comments, to be certain there were no warnings and rebuilt my scene while eliminating the warnings.  Voila!  UILabels.